# Using variables in Java within two if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, error-handling, syntax-error

So I am currently writing a program that asks the user for the degree of the polynomial they will be multiplying and then will multiply said polynomial. My program is set to only multiply up to the third polynomial. I use an if statement to check the degree, and then prompt the user for the number of coefficients needed. However, I have another if statement further in the program that uses these coefficients and assigns them to the product polynomial's coefficients. It says that I can't use the variable as it may have not been initialized?? I declared the variables all at the beginning of the code, not within the if statements but it still says it may have not been initialized. I'll include the code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
           if (degreeform == 1)
              {
                 degreeformstate = true;
                 
                 coef_A = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient a: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_B = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient b: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_C = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient c: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_D = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient d: ");
                 conIO.printEndlines(TWO_ENDLINES);
              }
           
           else if (degreeform == 2)
              {
                 degreeformstate = true;
                 
                 coef_A = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient a: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_B = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient b: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_C = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient c: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_D = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient d: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_E = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient e: ");
                 conIO.printEndlines(TWO_ENDLINES);
              }
           
           else if (degreeform == 3)
              {
                 degreeformstate = true;
                 
                 coef_A = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient a: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_B = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient b: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_C = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient c: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_D = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient d: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_E = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient e: ");
                 conIO.printEndline();
                 
                 coef_F = conIO.promptForInt("Enter coefficient f: ");
                 conIO.printEndlines(TWO_ENDLINES);
              }

           else 
              {
                 degreeformstate = false;
                 
                 conIO.printString("Incorrect number of polynomial degrees entered - Program Aborted");
                 System.exit(0);
              
              }

              if (degreeform == 1)
                 {
                    coef_V = coef_A * coef_C;
                    coef_W = (coef_B * coef_C) + (coef_A * coef_D);
                    coef_X = (coef_B * coef_D);
                 }
                 
              // polynomial type 2
              else if (degreeform == 2)
                 {
                    coef_V = coef_A * coef_C;
                    coef_W = (coef_B * coef_C) + (coef_A * coef_D);
                    coef_X = (coef_A * coef_E) + (coef_B * coef_D);
                    coef_Y = coef_B * coef_E;
                 }
              // polynomial type 3
              else 
                 {
                    coef_V = coef_A * coef_C;
                    coef_W = (coef_B * coef_C) + (coef_A * coef_D);
                    coef_X = (coef_A * coef_E) + (coef_B * coef_D);
                    coef_Y = (coef_A * coef_F)+ (coef_B * coef_E);
                    coef_Z = coef_B * coef_E;
                 }
```

Comment: If I were you, I would start with reducing duplicate code.

Comment: I edited the code, I cropped it wrong, now it includes the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare, but instead initialize your variables to their default values, either at the beginning of the code or in the else block.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it worked after I initialized them to zero and reassigned them after checking within the if statement. That seemed to work. In my previous programs, I didn't have to do that. I could initialize them without value, but with a type. Is there a reason why that works?

Comment: If you declare your the variables as a class variables - they will be initialised with default values (null for objects and primitive values for primitives). But if you instead declare the variables in a method body - you should self initialise them.
In your code example - you have 2 cases when variables are initialised ( first 2 if and else if blocks), and one case wenn the variables remain unitialised - else block.